# MongoDB Play Ground - MongoDB for VS Code - Export a Query or Pipeline to Language

Tags: mongodb

I am using MongoDB Playground of MongoDB Extension for VS Cide. As per the documentation in the below URLs. there is a provision of generating code from a highlighted query. However, when I highlight a query, I could not see any menu or option to generate code. I have attached the screen shot for your reference. Appreciate if any one can let me know what configuration to be done so that I can generate the code in Python ?
https://www.mongodb.com/docs/mongodb-vscode/export-to-language/
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mongodb.mongodb-vscode
Thanks and regards,
Prasad

[image: MongoDB Playground Screen Capture]

Comment: Did you click the lightbulb ?